# Power Analysis for 2-Way-Anova in R

Tags: r, anova, statistical-power, gpower

I did a power analysis to calculate the sample size in G*Power.
Now I'd like to do the same in R. However, I am not able to figure out how...
I found [ss.2way](https://rdrr.io/cran/pwr2/src/R/ss.2way.R) but that seems to require different inputs.
Is there any way to calculate the sample size for a 2x3 design in R?
Thanks in advance.
This is the G*Power input/output
[image]

Comment: Do you want to calculate power for the main effect(s) or for the interaction between your 2 factors?

Comment: Look at the Superpower package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Superpower/

Comment: WebPower package wp.kanova function might also work.

Comment: Note, as entered, this will give you the power for either the interaction or the 3-categorical factor.  Numerator df would have to be 1 for the other main effect.

Comment: Ye, WebPower seems to be doing the job.